# Difference between NumericUpDown.Text and NumericUpdown.Value

Tags: c#, .net

What is difference between NumericUpDown.Text and NumericUpdown.Value?

May Text and Value Property dependent relation or completely independent?

Comment: This is easily answered by reading the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown_properties.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  `numericUpDown1.Value` typically references a `public decimal Value { get; set; }` which is decimal based on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx

and `NumericUpDown.Tex`t references  public virtual `string Text { get; set; }` which is string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs40s7ds.aspx

Comment: And important to note - the docs state this about the text property: "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." Which answers the second question - will they ever differ - Answer: Only if you have done something very wrong by setting the Text property in your code.

Comment: @Cold Told :  what is relation between ?

Answer (score 0):

The Text property, as its name implies, returns the textual (string) representation of the control. It is defined by a base class and is overridden in the NumericUpDown control.

The Value property should always be use because it deals with a numeric (decimal) value.

Comment: in numbericUpDown after .Net 2008 we can't type string char (just type number character) , what is difference value and text in numbericupdown after text validation (not in edititing)?